# Material Design custom view theme

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to have a default theme with a button.  When I do this the button no longer ripples.  I believe I need to set a proper parent on the btn_normal style but I can not find the appropiate theme.

btn_normal style works fine if I just apply it via a style to the button directly.

I have tried tons of parents and none of them have worked.  Let me know if you have ran into this.  Thanks.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/btn_normal</item>
</style>

<style name="btn_normal">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [RippleDrawable](https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable) third party library. By that, you can give Ripple effect for Android 7+ version.